# Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(AddChildActivity, int, void)'

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(com.alburraq.mapschoolbus.activities.AddChildActivity, int, void)'

I want to show arraylist in autoCompletetextview

```
for (int i = 0; i < Constants.followArrayList.size(); i++) {

        loadVehicles(Constants.followArrayList.get(i).getOwnerID());

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, loadVehicles(Constants.followArrayList.get(i).getOwnerID()) );
        mAutocompleteTextViewBus.setThreshold(1); //will start working from first character
        mAutocompleteTextViewBus.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

private void loadVehicles(final String ownerID) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("vehicles").orderByChild("ownerId").equalTo(ownerID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

                    vehicle.setId("" + postSnapshot.getKey());
                    vehicle.setDriverName("" + postSnapshot.child("driverName").getValue());
                    vehicle.setDriverPhone("" + postSnapshot.child("driverPhone").getValue());
                    vehicle.setDriverPin("" + postSnapshot.child("driverPin").getValue());
                    vehicle.setImage("" + postSnapshot.child("image").getValue());
                    vehicle.setIsActive(Integer.parseInt("" + postSnapshot.child("isActive").getValue()));
                    vehicle.setLatitude("" + postSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue());
                    vehicle.setLongitude("" + postSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue());
                    vehicle.setNumber("" + postSnapshot.child("number").getValue());
                    vehicle.setOwnerId("" + postSnapshot.child("ownerId").getValue());

                    // if (vehicle.getIsActive() == 1) {
                    vehicles.add(vehicle);
                    //}
                }
                Constants.dismissSpinner();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Constants.dismissSpinner();
                loadVehicles(ownerID);
            }
        });
        Constants.dismissSpinner();
    }
```

> Cannot resolve constructor
>   'ArrayAdapter(com.alburraq.mapschoolbus.activities.AddChildActivity,
>   int, void)'

Answer (score 0):

In the `ArrayAdapter` the [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#public-constructors_1) `ArrayAdapter(context, int, void)` **doesn't** exist.

You are using:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, loadVehicles(Constants.followArrayList.get(i).getOwnerID()) );
```

and `loadVehicles(final String ownerID)` returns `void`.

Use one of these constructors:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

Comment: what should i return because this method nothing need to return

Comment: @SaqibJavaid it depends by your goal. You can use a List<String> objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the line:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, loadVehicles(Constants.followArrayList.get(i).getOwnerID()) );
```

The only generic constructors `ArrayAdapter` has are ([from the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter)):

> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) Constructor
>
> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
>   Constructor
>
> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects) Constructor.
>
> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
>   T[] objects) Constructor.
>
> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects)
>   Constructor
>
> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
>   List objects) Constructor

You will need to return a value if you want to pass in a response from your `loadVehicles` method. Currently you have: `private **void** loadVehicles(final String ownerID)`.